# Cygwin + windows 10 error "sigfillset was not declared in the scope"

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, boost, g++

I am trying to compile code on windows with Cygwin. The code currently, compiles successfully on Linux. 
Here are the steps I followed to compile the code on Windows 10.

1) I installed Cygwin on my windows 10 machine. 
2) Installed gcc , g++ , boost from the installation package of cygwin. 
3) Added cygwin path in environment variable.
When I compile the code, it throws the following errors.

```
usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_signal_blocker.hpp: In constructor ‘boost::asio::detail::posix_signal_blocker::posix_signal_blocker()’:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_signal_blocker.hpp:42:25: error: ‘sigfillset’ was not declared in this scope
     sigfillset(&new_mask);
                         ^
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_signal_blocker.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::posix_signal_blocker::block()’:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_signal_blocker.hpp:59:27: error: ‘sigfillset’ was not declared in this scope
       sigfillset(&new_mask);
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/signal_set_service.hpp:213:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/signal_set_service.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_signal_set.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:27,
                 from ../src/app/macl/net/TrxcomInboundReader.h:10,
                 from ../src/app/macl/net/TrxcomInboundReader.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp: In member function  boost::system::error_code boost::asio::detail::signal_set_service::add(boost::asio::detail::signal_set_service::implementation_type&, int, boost::system::error_code&)’:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp:266:29: error: ‘sigfillset’ was not declared in this scope
       sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
                             ^
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp:267:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘sigaction::sigaction(int&, sigaction*, int)’
       if (::sigaction(signal_number, &sa, 0) == -1)
                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/sys/signal.h:112:0,
                 from /usr/include/signal.h:6,
                 from /usr/include/pthread.h:12,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/core/demangle.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/core/typeinfo.hpp:119,
                 from /usr/include/boost/detail/sp_typeinfo.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base.hpp:5 ,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from ../src/app/macl/net/TrxcomInboundReader.h:8,
                 from ../src/app/macl/net/TrxcomInboundReader.cc:1:
/usr/include/cygwin/signal.h:317:8: note: candidate: sigaction::sigaction()
 struct sigaction
        ^
/usr/include/cygwin/signal.h:317:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
/usr/include/cygwin/signal.h:317:8: note: candidate: sigaction::sigaction(const sigaction&)
/usr/include/cygwin/signal.h:317:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/signal_set_service.hpp:213:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/signal_set_service.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_signal_set.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:27,
```

Let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at Cygwin's [`signal.h`](https://github.com/Alexpux/Cygwin/blob/master/newlib/libc/include/sys/signal.h) you will see that `sigaction` and `sigfillset` (the two functions your error messages say are missing) are defined inside a guard:

```
#if __BSD_VISIBLE || __XSI_VISIBLE >= 4
```

Those two names are double-underscored to indicate that you aren't supposed to set them directly yourself.  So see [`features.h`](https://github.com/Alexpux/Cygwin/blob/master/newlib/libc/include/sys/features.h) which explains more.

So you need to add one of these two things to your compilation commands:

```
-D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
```

Or

```
-D_GNU_SOURCE
```

Or

```
-D_BSD_SOURCE
```

Then the missing functions will be available to Boost.  You may have some definitions somewhere in your code which preempt the above--for example if you have `_POSIX_SOURCE` defined anywhere that could stop it from working.

Comment: Thanks -D_GNU_SOURCE made the progress. Now, I am stuck at linking stage where it fails to find libftdi1 and libboost                        Linking test_app
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibftdi1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile.test:105: bin/testl_app] Error 1